# How to create a matrix which contains a selected set of pixels from another matrix based on a third one?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a grayscale matrix A with certain values that are black(i.e., pixel values of 0). I have another grayscale matrix B which is of the same size as A.

I want to create a matrix C which contains only those values of B where A is 0 and the rest of the values in B turn to white. For example,

```
A = [0 35 0 0 88];
B = [22 3 34 99 4];
```

The matrix C should be

```
C= [22 255 34 99 255];
```

I'm trying to use logical indexing as follows but it has errors.

```
C(A==0)=B;
C(A~=0)=255;
```

How do I change the above line to get the desired results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to assign the whole of `B` to the smaller matrix of just locations where `A==0`.

In order to use only the correct number of values for assignment, the first line needs to be

`C(A==0)=B(A==0);`

It should be noted however that the same result can be gained simply by setting all of `C` to the corresponding `B` values (`C = B`) and then just modifying those where `A~=0` as in your 2nd line.